# N1QL Query ARRAY_CONTAINS speed

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have the documents of the following form that I need to query:

```
{
  "id": "-KWiJ1LlYbXSSRUmocwK",
  "ownerID": "72f16d9d-b905-498c-a7ff-9702cdcae996",
  "orgID": "20071513",
  "teams": [
    "5818f7a75f84c800079186a8",
    "5818cbb25f84c800079186a7"
  ]
}
```

And I'll want to be able to query based on ownerID and the teams array.  My query currently looks like so:

```
SELECT id FROM
default AS p 
WHERE p.ownerID = $1
OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(p.teams, $2)
ORDER BY id
```

So I can get documents with the expected ownerID as well as documents that have a specific team id in the teams array. This query does work, but I'm concerned about performance when I have a lot of documents, and possibly some documents have up to 20 teams assigned.

Am I on the right track?

EDIT: Couchbase ver 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couchbase 4.5 introduced array indexing. This allows you to index individual elements of an array, in your case the teams array. This will be essential for the performance of your query. With 4.5.1 or 4.6, you will do:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_owner ON default( ownerID );
CREATE INDEX idx_teams ON default( DISTINCT ARRAY t FOR t IN teams END );

SELECT id
FROM default AS p
WHERE p.ownerID = $1
UNION
SELECT id
FROM default AS p
WHERE ANY t IN p.teams SATISFIES t = $2 END;
```

Comment: Yeah I'm using community right now, so I belive I'm stuck on 4.1 for the time being, but I'll definitely upgrade when possible.

Comment: Also after doing some testing on using WHERE ANY vs ARRAY_CONTAINS (at least in 4.1), ARRAY_CONTAINS seems to win out on speed by a little bit.

Comment: A gotcha I discovered on this:  you *must* use the same variable name (t in this example) for both the CREATE INDEX and the SELECT.  If they don't match, the query may work but much slower, because the query planner won't use the index (even given a USE INDEX).